# SoftLayer API - SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::editObject does not update isReserved

Tags: python, ip-address, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using SoftLayer's Python client, I'm trying to update the `SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress` object's `isReserved` field to True, but it doesn't appear to work.

I call `SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::editObject` method, and pass in `{'isReserved' : True}`.

Here is how I call it:

```
client.call('SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress', 'editObject',
            {'isReserved': True}, id=123456)
```

The return value is True, indicating success, but the IpAddress still doesn't have it set to True.

Would appreciate if you can tell me why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set the **isReserved** flag, because this is for internal purposes, when an ip cannot be used for some particular reason, you will not able set this

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification. I assume you are actually part of SoftLayer, i.e., this is SoftLayer's official confirmation?

Comment: Yep, I'm part from SoftLayer's API support team